# How to get pending transaction counts using web3-react?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, metamask, react

I'm sure this question was asked before, but I did not find any result that helped my problem.
I wanna get pending transaction counts in Metamask using web3-react.
Are there any simple solutions that don't use web3-react?

Comment: Hi Figaro27! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Can you describe what are you trying to achieve? Some web3 providers don't support certain apis because of performance reasons.

Comment: I want to show pending transaction counts on Dapp.
When a user submits a transaction, there are some minutes or seconds to get a response. At that period, I want to show '1 pending transaction' on the header.

Comment: If the provider supports it `web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addr, "pending")` should return the total transaction by `addr` including pending transactions and ``web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addr)` is the total confirmed transactions.